# Spark streaming can we create a thread on executor

Tags: multithreading, apache-spark, rdd

I have a question on spark streaming. In my spark streaming application, I have a code that runs on worker/executor as a task (inside foreachPartition() while processing a RDD). I want to create a thread as part of this code that will run continuously on executor/worker from the time it is launched till executor is alive, listen to some external events and take some action based on that.

Is this possible to do in spark streaming?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to fit this into a custom receive. You can find some details in [Implementing a Custom Receiver](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-custom-receivers.html#implementing-a-custom-receiver). Otherwise it doesn't fit very well in the Spark streaming.

It is possible to start thread on the drive but I understand it is not what you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick reply. Actually there is one library that I am using in my code which runs on executor/worker. This library spawns a thread, and creates one connection with storage (cassandra) and other connection with storage manager. Storage manager informs my library code (thread) whenever a change happens in storage, so that library code (thread) can fetch those changes and keep them in local cache for future lookup by spark tasks/jobs. Does this go well with Spark?